# ¿Cómo optimizar subconsulta count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy realizando un script para obtener notificaciones de documentos no vistos, para lo cual tengo una tabla que posee los siguientes campos:

```
 id_notificacion | visto | id_doc_interno | id_doc_externo | id_doc_pago
-----------------+-------+----------------+----------------+------------
      0          |  true |       0        |                |  
      1          |  true |                |       0        |     
      2          |  false|                |                |    0
```

Entonces para obtener el conteo de todos los documentos no leídos realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
select 
(select count(*) from notificacion where visto = false and id_documento_interno is not null) as interno,
(select count(*) from notificacion where visto = false and id_documento_externo is not null) as externo,
(select count(*) from notificacion where visto = false and id_documento_pago is not null) as pago
```

lo que me devuelve:

```
interno | externo | pago
--------+---------+-----
   0    |    0    |  1
```

Funciona correctamente. Sin embargo mi pregunta es:

**¿Se podría optimizar de alguna manera, ya sea usando joins o alguna clausula adicional?**

He revisado la siguiente pregunta pero no me queda del todo claro.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799820/when-to-use-sql-sub-queries-versus-a-standard-join

Comment: A la primera pregunta algunos dirán que si otros que no, y otros más que depende de cada caso, y todos tendrán razón en alguna medida. ¿Se puede editar la pregunta para evitar que parezca que pides opiniones?

Comment: @toledano acabo de editarla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece que las subcosultas son innecesarias, dado que todo lo que buscas es de condición `visto = false`, y si `id_doc_interno`, los otros 2 son nulos puedes hacer:

```
select
    count(id_doc_interno) as interno,
    count(id_doc_externo) as externo,
    count(id_doc_pago) as pago
from
    notificacion
where
    visto = false;
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Y por supuesto, el rendimiento es mejor que el de subconsultas porque solo se necesita recorrer la tabla una sola vez en vez de 3.

Comment: ¿Y cómo se evalúan los no nulos, ya que al parecer en el código de la pregunta quería verificar que los ids no fueran nulos?

Comment: @A. Cedano: `COUNT(expresion)` solo cuenta los registros cuando `expresion` no es `null`.

Comment: @sstan Ok, gracias. +1 que lo hayas explicado en tu respuesta.

Comment: @sstan sólo cuenta los no nulos? No tenía idea!

Answer (score 3):

Solo para ampliar la excelente respuesta de Sergio1871:

Con tu consulta, hay que recorrer la tabla 3 veces. Para evitar eso, el patrón a seguir es de usar un `COUNT` condicional de forma que solo se necesita recorrer la tabla una vez.

La forma tradicional de hacerlo es algo como esto:

```
select count(case when id_documento_interno is not null then 'X' end) as interno,
       count(case when id_documento_externo is not null then 'X' end) as externo,
       count(case when id_documento_pago is not null then 'X' end) as pago
  from notificacion
 where visto = false
```

Pero siendo que todas las condiciones dentro de los `COUNT` son `IS NOT NULL`, se puede simplificar con la consulta que propuso Sergio1871 donde te evitas de definir una expresión `CASE` dentro del `COUNT`.

Aun así, es bueno conocer la forma mas general de hacerlo en caso necesitas hacer algo similar, pero donde no todas las condiciones son `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Genial gracias por la explicación +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

En SQL muchas veces es necesario corroborar, incorporar, ignorar o consultar datos a diferentes tablas con los comandos básicos que todos deberíamos de conocer: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE y DELETE, y para esto, se pueden crear subconsultas.

La verdad para alguien purista del SQL, las ve como algo del demonio ya que se pueden utilizar los JOINs para hacer lo mismo (Corroborar, incorporar, ignorar o consultar).

Quizás algunas de las ventajas de las consultas podrían ser:

- Estructurar de mejor forma el query: Quizás hoy en día sea muy fácil estructurar un comando gracias a las bases de datos relacionales. Sin embargo, si alguna vez te llegas a encontrar una base de datos sin relaciones y tengas que consultas varias tablas, tendrías que utilizar demasiados JOINs, haciendo más complejo el entendimiento.
- Dividir/Aislar las consultas en subconsultas: Por el punto anterior, permite probar pequeñas partes del query para tener un mejor entendimiento de lo que realmente quieres obtener.
- Si no es tu fuerte: Supongo que puede ser una alternativa para los que comienzan en el mundo de SQL :)
- Legibilidad: Para algunas personas, puede ser más fácil de 'leer' el contexto de la consulta.

Y como todo, no todo lo que brilla es oro. Algunas desventajas podrían ser:

- Costo elevado de ejecución: En la práctica, las subconsultas pueden consumir más tiempo y memoria cuando se incrementa el numero de anidamientos.
- Optimización: Por el punto anterior, a veces requieren optimizarse.
- JOINs: ¿Para qué utilizar subconsultas? Cuando pueden resolverse mayoritariamente con JOINs.

Contestando a tu pregunta. Más que una buena práctica, creo que a veces son un malnecesario dependiendo el tipo de problema que estemos enfrentando en un proyecto.

Para terminar, te dejo los siguientes links ["Usando subconsultas en SQL para reducir la complejidad de nuestros queries"](http://geeks.ms/sergiotarrillo/2007/02/16/usando-subconsultas-en-sql-para-reducir-la-complejidad-de-nuestros-queries/) y ["The Power of Subqueries"](http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_subqueries.html).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y la informacion adicional +1 :)